# Average case complexity of search data structures

Tags: data-structures, search-algorithms

Algorithms are generally studied in terms of average case complexity and worst case complexity? Is there also a kind of analysis called "average worst case" complexity?

Comment: What would that look like? The average over the worst 10% of cases, for example?

Comment: @PeterLeupold I was thinking about algorithms that depend on random coins. The choice of these random coins could sometimes lead to poor efficiency. We then compute the average complexity considering the worst choices.

Answer (score 2):

One such notion is that of [smoothed analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothed_analysis), in which we compute the worst-case expected complexity of an algorithm on a randomly perturbed input. In more detail, let $N(x)$ be a randomly perturbed version of $x$, and let $T$ be the time complexity of the algorithm. Then we are interested in
$$
\sup_x \mathbb E[T(N(x))].
$$
The "worst case" aspect is with respect to the unperturbed input, and the "average case" aspect is with respect to the perturbation.

The simplex algorithm has been shown to be polynomial time in this sense, although its worst case complexity is exponential.

Comment: Thank you ! Again ! :-) . Are you aware of a notion in which we compute the average complexity of a probabilistic algorithm by considering the worst choices of random coins?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would do that. It is better to just fix them arbitrarily and analyze the corresponding deterministic algorithm.

Comment: Because I think these random choices can completely determine the efficiency of the algorithm. It is motivated by the fact that a worst case input is often "isolated", not representative of the average worst case.

Comment: After I have read again your answer, I understand that worst case should better analysed depending on the distribution of the input. But, concerning non-deterministic algorithms, are there types of analysis that are focusing on the complexity of the algorithm depending on the distribution of the coin tosses, rather than on the input distribution ?

Comment: Pseudorandomness focuses on what assumptions on the coin tosses are needed to guarantee a random-like behavior.

Comment: Thank you Yuval. Should I reformulate my problem in another post ? It seems there are different ways to compute the complexity of a non-deterministic algorithm: 1) worst case with the least favourable input, but an ideal distribution of coins for the internal operations of the algorithm; 2) average case considering a distribution of inputs, always considering ideal distribution of coins; 3) average worst case considering the distribution of coins quite distant from its theoritical one. 4) combination of 1 with 3 ?

Comment: Yes, this merits another post in which you make it clear what exactly you're looking for.